# foo.substr gives "Is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Jquery's datepicker plugin (which works fine). Then I need to extract the "day of the week" from the picked date.

When using `foo.substring(0,3)` to assign the first three characters of the `datepicker('getDate')` I get: `TypeError foo.substr is not a function`.

```
$(function () {
    $("#textDatepicker").datepicker();
});

function selectedDay() {
    var foo = $("#textDatepicker").datepicker('getDate');

    //IF USED.... alert(foo);
    //retuens (for example)..... 
    //"Thu Jul 18 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)"

    var weekday = foo.substr(0, 3)
    document.getElementById("dayofweek").innerHTML = "The day of the week selected is: " + weekday;
}

<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://jquery-blog-js.googlecode.com/files/SetCase.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
</head>
<body>
Select Date:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="textDatepicker" onchange="selectedDay();">
<br><br>
<span id="dayofweek">Selected day of week replaces this</span>
</body>
```

I have also pasted at: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pvz4E/2/)

Any help would be appreciated.. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why do you load both jQuery 1.9.1 and 1.10.2 (latest.min.js)?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that it's a string, but not an object, that you're trying to take the substring of?

Comment: My guess would be that .substr only works on strings and you are trying to work on a jQuery object.

Comment: Haven't work hardly anything using jquery. Thanks for pointing things out. I'll need to workout how to get the value in to a variable.

Comment: Um, the documentation says that [getDate returns a `Date`, not a string](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate).

Comment: Thank you adeneo .. would have taken me more than 5 to work that one out...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var foo = $("#textDatepicker").datepicker('getDate');
```

returns a Date object, not a string, and has no method `substr()`

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pvz4E/3/)

You can solve it by removing that unsightly inline event handler and doing :

```
$("#textDatepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        var day  = $.datepicker.formatDate('DD', date);
        $('#dayofweek').html(day);
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pvz4E/6/)

Comment: `foo.toString().substr(0, 3);` will do it.

Comment: @SheikhHeera - That's great, but stringifying a date object and extracting stuff from the string doesn't really seem like the right way to work with date objects !

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
var weekday = foo.toString().substr(0, 3);
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/Pvz4E/5/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#textDatepicker").datepicker('getDate');
```

is an object. You can't take the substring of an object with substr.

Answer (score 0):

foo.substr(0,3) is the culprit. It returns a date object and you can do substr on a date object. 
You could fix the problem by using the code below

```
function selectedDay() {
    var foo = $("#textDatepicker").datepicker('getDate');

    //IF USED.... alert(foo);
    //retuens (for example)..... 
    //"Thu Jul 18 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)"

    var weekday = foo.getDay();
    document.getElementById("dayofweek").innerHTML = "The day of the week selected is: " + weekday;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

called the `toString();` method before calling the `subString();`
like `foo.toString().subString(start,length);`
Worked for me